# Restrict credentials access using credentials domains in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, credentials, role-based-access-control

I have teams (eng & prod) that share the same folder in Jenkins. they are using the same pipeline, which takes as param some credentials (credID= variable_${env} where env can be prod or eng).
I have created two credential domains inside the folder, Eng-secrets & Prod-secrets.
Knowing that I use role based access control, is there a way to restrict access to credentials in a way eng team will access only Eng-secrets credentials domain, and prod team will access only Prod-secrets credentials domain
Thank you.

Comment: is it not feasible in jenkins?